# How dynamic action login_form_{action} is working

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, actions

I found this action hook in wp-login.php file. It says it can be used to create custom actions to the wp-login. However, as I'm new to WP coding and PHP, I do not understand how {action} can work even though it is under double quotations? Here is the action hook:

```
do_action( "login_form_{$action}" );
```

In the plugin that I'm following, this action hook is added by this:

```
add_action( 'login_form_login', array( $this, 'redirect_to_custom_login' ));
```

How does login_form_login matches and replaces login_form_{action} ?

Comment: Please adjust the question's title, to make it more readable, thanks. Are you asking how "dynamic" actions compares to "static" actions? Or how actions works in general?

Answer (score 3):

This is a *dynamic* hook:

```
do_action( "login_form_{$action}" );
```

Meaning that it depends on the `$action` variable.

There are other such hooks used in the WordPress core.

You can check out the naming convention for dynamic hooks in the *Core Contributor Handbook* [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#interpolation-for-naming-dynamic-hooks). It's says e.g.:

> Dynamic hooks should be named using interpolation rather than
>   concatenation for readability and discoverability purposes.

*Double quoted* strings in PHP can parse variables, that's why it's not written with *single quotes*:

```
do_action( 'login_form_{$action}' );
```

Check out the *curly syntax* in the PHP docs in the [variable parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) section.

**Example:**

If we have:

```
$action = 'login';
```

then it will generate the following action:

```
do_action( "login_form_login" );
```

that plugins can hook into via:

```
add_action( 'login_form_login', ... );
```

Answer (score 1):

`$action` is a variable that is set on line 384 of wp-login.php (as of WordPress 4.7.3).

```
$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : 'login';
```

When WordPress gets to line 428, it evaluates the string inside the double quotations first as `login_form_login` if the `$_REQUEST['action']` variable is not set. If that variable is set, for instance as `register`, then the string inside the double quotations would be evaluated as `login_form_register`.

When the the WordPress function `do_action()` is interpreted, see [line 421 of wp-includes/plugin.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/plugin.php#L421), does some stuff, and on line 453 applies the `do_action()` method of the `$wp_filter` global.

To see what this method does, we need to go to [line 321 of wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php#L321), which because hooks are just simplified filters, calls the `apply_filters()` method, which is on line 276 of the same file.

The relevant parts of this method are lines 296, 298, and 300 and they look like:

```
$value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array() );
```

[`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) is a PHP function that calls a callback with an array of parameters.

WordPress stores the callbacks for each hook in the `$wp_filter` global. We add them using the `add_action()` and `add_filter()` functions.

```
add_action( 'login_form_login', array( $this, 'redirect_to_custom_login' ));
```

This is telling WordPress to add an action to the `login_form_login` hook and the callable callback is the `redirect_to_custom_login` method from `$this` object.